How to log raw Kafka message in Java Spring along with partition and offset?
When my app consumes Kafka messages, I would like to have a single log line that captures the raw Kafka message body (JSON in my case) along with the topic, partition, and offset for the message.  I've tried implementing a RecordInterceptor, but that doesn't appear to have access to the raw message before the Deserializer processes it, and the Deserializer doesn't have access to the partition or offset. Obviously if I have a log with topic, partition, and offset I can go look up the original message after the fact, but it would be more convenient to have all four together in one place where it is processed.

The ConsumerRecord has what you need. The deserializer only accepts the topic name content bytes and record headers; it has no need for offset or partition metadata.
The RecordInterceptor has access to such record. I'd recommend only logging on an exception. There's little purpose to log every single event, IMO.
You can also use KafkaStreams peek function for the same.

ConsmerRecord does have a value field, but it's not the raw value, it's the one produced by the Deserializer.

@KCBaltz I was referring to "the topic, partition, and offset for the message"

Unfortunately, the key point of my question is getting those three values PLUS the raw message value in the same place so they can be logged together.

@KCBaltz In that case, you'd use ByteArrayDeserializer. Then you can chain/compose the necessary "downstream" deserializer at runtime, after logging the raw data. I thought you can use interceptors for the same, but havent used those in depth.

I can see where that would work, but it does mean manually triggering the real deserialization process, potentially in a bunch of places.  I will give it some thought.  If you want to revise your answer to this, I'll upvote it.
